# graph of a function Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I am making a temperature circuit with arduino.
is there any way to plot the value of the temperature in a graph using arduino?
thank you very much in advance

Comment: Yes, there are many many ways of doing it. What kind of graph do you want, and where do you want to display it?

Comment: On what? A TFT screen? LCD screen? On your computer? A slice of processed cheese?  And do you want to see live data or analyse historical data? You need to give *specifics* or we can't help you.

Comment: yes, on my computer. and I want to see Data in real time

Comment: Do you want to program your own graphing system or use an off-the shelf product?

Comment: Did you just casually drop the Matlab requirement in your comment? If so, please edit you question to reflect this requirement. Otherwise, if you want something simple, [use processing to graph the data](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Graph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the [Plot](https://blog.arduino.cc/2015/11/03/arduino-ide-1-6-6-released-and-available-for-download/) menu command in the new Arduino 1.6.6 or you can use the [Visual Micro debugger](http://www.visualmicro.com/post/2015/08/16/Arduino-Breakpoint-Command-Syntax-Plotting-Values-Example.aspx) to create graphs in Visual Studio

Comment: I tried with new arduino 1.6.6 but I don't know how to use the plotter. in the menu i found Serial plotter, can you tell me how can I do to plot my function ?

Comment: it works. because if we want to plot we cannot write; 
`Serial.print("Output is :"); Serial.println(Output)`;  so we have to write just :
`Serial.println(Output);`

Comment: Yes that's right. In visual micro you can have multiple values with descriptions without editing your code. In Arduino you have simpler system and must change your code to use Serial.println(number) :)